# Doctrine query builder - run query on Many To Many Entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using query builder to perform queries on Many to Many Entity in my application. Problem is that doctrine query builder doesn't use "Many To Many" table that is used to store data between two entities.

When I join them using mapped variables in Entity, doctrine query builder joins "parent" tables which leads to incorrect result.

I am not sure why it does and how to fix my code to work correctly.

Does someone knows where is the problem?

This is query I want to run (working query that I want to run using doctrine query builder):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1) AS total,
  gz.fleet_id AS type,
  MIN(bv.passenger_seats_number) AS min,
  MAX(bv.passenger_seats_number) AS max
FROM bus_vehicle AS bv

INNER JOIN company_stations AS cs
  ON cs.company_id = bv.company_id

INNER JOIN bus_vehicle_group_size AS gz
  ON (bv.passenger_seats_number BETWEEN gz.min AND gz.max)

WHERE cs.stations_id = 1

GROUP BY gz.fleet_id
```

Doctrine query:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('bv')
        ->select('COUNT(1) as total, bt.type as busType, MIN(bv.passengerSeatsNumber) as minPersons, MAX(bv.passengerSeatsNumber) as maxPersons')
        ->join('bv.company', 'c')
        ->join('c.stations', 's')
        ->join('AppBundle:GroupSizeBusVehicle', 'gz', 'WITH', 'bv.passengerSeatsNumber >= gz.min AND bv.passengerSeatsNumber <= gz.max')
        ->join('gz.fleetType', 'bt')
        ->where('s.id = :stationId')
        ->setParameter('stationId', $stationId)
        ->groupBy('bv.busType')
        ->getQuery();
 dump ($query->getResult());
```

Entity and mappings:

Bus Vehicles:

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Company
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="busVehicle")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $company;
```

Company:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Stations", inversedBy="company")
 */
private $stations;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BusVehicle", mappedBy="company")
 */

private $busVehicle;
```

Stations:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company", mappedBy="stations")
 */
private $company;
```

Generated doctrine query from my code:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(1) AS sclr_0, 
  b0_.type AS type_1, 
  MIN(b1_.passenger_seats_number) AS sclr_2, 
  MAX(b1_.passenger_seats_number) AS sclr_3 
FROM 
  bus_vehicle b1_ 
  INNER JOIN company c2_ ON b1_.company_id = c2_.id 
  INNER JOIN company_stations c4_ ON c2_.id = c4_.company_id 
  INNER JOIN stations s3_ ON s3_.id = c4_.stations_id 
  INNER JOIN bus_vehicle_group_size b5_ ON (
    b1_.passenger_seats_number >= b5_.min 
    AND b1_.passenger_seats_number <= b5_.max
  ) 
  INNER JOIN bus_types b0_ ON b5_.fleet_id = b0_.id 
WHERE 
  s3_.id = ? 
GROUP BY 
  b1_.bus_type
```

**EDIT**

Expected results (from first query)

```
+-------+------+-----+-----+
| total | type | min | max |
+-------+------+-----+-----+
|     1 |    1 |  20 |  20 |
|     5 |    2 |  40 |  55 |
|     4 |    3 |  10 |  15 |
+-------+------+-----+-----+
```

Query results I get when I run it with doctrine:

```
 0 => array:4 [▼
    "total" => "7"
    "busType" => "2"
    "minPersons" => "15"
    "maxPersons" => "55"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "total" => "3"
    "busType" => "3"
    "minPersons" => "10"
    "maxPersons" => "15"
```

Comment: what do you mean by "When I join them using mapped variables in Entity, doctrine query builder joins "parent" tables which leads to incorrect result."? Please add the results to the question.

Comment: @lordrhodos I edited my post with generated doctrine query. Problem is that doctrine joins parent tables which leads to incorrect result and with unnecessary joins

Comment: the problem is that you are using AND instead of BETWEEN, and group by on different fields.